# Trying to initialize a class variable in Python with conditions

Tags: python, class, while-loop, initialization, instance

I am trying to create a class Statistician in Python.

This statistician class have 3 attributes: Each of them can have integer values (integer) ranging from 0 to 100 :

1. logic
2. memory
3. creativite

This class will have the method below :

initialization(): a method that randomly assigns a value to the 3 attributes by making the total sum be between 111 and 177, excluding even values and multiples of 5. This method will be launched by the constructor of the object.

I had code this :

```
import random

class Statisticien:

    def __init__(self):

        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        somme = a + b + c

        while somme >= 177 and somme <= 111 and (a%2 == 0) and (a%5 == 5) and (b%2 == 0) and(b%5 == 5) and (c%2 == 0) and (c%5 == 5) :
        a = random.randint(0,178)
        b = random.randint(0,178)
        c = random.randint(0,178)

        self.logique = a
        self.memoire = b
        self.creativite = c

    test = Statisticien()
    print(test.logique)
    print(test.memoire
    print(test.creativite)
    >>>
    0
    0
    0
```

This code assigned 0 to my attributes logique, memoire and creativite but i can't understand why because with my condition While the numbers a, b and c are modified juste after. Can someone help me to understand why ? and perhaps explain how to manage my problem ?

Comment: Please copy the code with proper indentation because it is a syntax element in python and if it is wrong everything is ambigous.

Comment: any `int x % 5` can never be equal to 5

Answer (score 0):

The while condition seemed to be too complicated.

Try this:

```
import random

class Statisticien:

    def __init__(self):

        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        somme = a + b + c

        while (somme <=111 or somme >= 177 or somme%2 == 0 or somme%5 == 0): 
            a = random.randint(0,178)
            b = random.randint(0,178)
            c = random.randint(0,178)

            somme = a + b + c
            self.logique = a
            self.memoire = b
            self.creativite = c

test = Statisticien()
print(test.logique)
print(test.memoire)
print(test.creativite)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem is that all the 3 variables a, b and c must not be even and not multiples of 5 (not  the total of the three)

Answer (score 0):

I finaly succeed with this code :

```
import random

class Statisticien:

    def __init__(self):

        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        somme = a + b + c

        while (somme >= 177) or (somme <= 111) or (a%2 == 0) or (a%5 == 0) or (b%2 == 0) or (b%5 == 0) or (c%2 == 0) or (c%5 == 0): 
            a = random.randint(0,178)
            b = random.randint(0,178)
            c = random.randint(0,178)

            somme = a + b + c
            self.logique = a
            self.memoire = b
            self.creativite = c
```